# Htaccess remove multiple substring or hide subdirectory(s)

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
http://www.example.com/blog/demo/first-post
http://www.example.com/blog/test/second-post
```

I would like to rewrite the above url to following with htaccess,

```
http://www.example.com/first-post
http://www.example.com/second-post
```

Simply,

If requested uri contains substring 'blog' it should remove 'blog' and the next item and concatinate the remains with firstpart

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/.*?/(.*)$  $1  [NC,L]
```